# Реализация автовхода в windows с экрана блокировки на c#

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать свою реализацию таких программ, которые при наличии USB-ключа (флешки) автоматически входят в систему, а при его отсутствии - блокируют. Со вторым я разобрался, а вот что делать со входом?Мне подойдёт любой способ, лишь бы было проще. Гугл ничего не дал. Многие ссылались, что это невозможно, однако такой софт есть. Может есть где почитать или примеры? С ключа планирую считывать текстовый файл (возможно зашифрую). Там будут либо реальные учетные данные пользователя если так можно, либо если они не нужны (какой-то другой способ), то пропишу свой идентификатор (придуманный, дабы подчеркнуть уникальность ключа).

Comment: Не думаю что это возможно, тем более средствами C#. Смотрите в сторону аппаратных ключей FIDO2, они поддерживаются в качестве аутентификации при входе в систему.

Comment: `возможно зашифрую` а разве это безопасно в открытом виде хранить пароль? Тогда уж можно сделать эмулятор клавиатуры на STM32, который посылает записанный пароль при подключении.

Comment: Поищите тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/authentication-functions